# Finding values using .text() in separate tr's in table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

What I am trying to do is separate the three table rows in this table, and have jQuery treat them individually to find the separate values (like price and SKU - you'll see in the fiddle link below).

Because the table is generated dynamically and all the classes are the same for each product, I am trying to define each tr as a separate variant, and then search through them to get the values using .text().

Here's a bit of code (jsfiddle link below):

**jQuery:**

```
var firstprice = $('#checkout .orderitems table.wizrtable tbody tr td.priceeach').text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
//price of a single product in checkout

var amountofproducts = $('#checkout .wizrtable tbody tr').length;
//amount of table rows in the actual checkout table structure


$(document).ready(function () {
    if (+amountofproducts >= 4 && +amountofproducts <= 8) {
        // Define unit price
        var firstrow = $('.wizrtable').closest('table').children('tr:first');
        var firstprice = $(firstrow()('#checkout .orderitems table.wizrtable tbody tr td.priceeach')).text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
        var secondrow = $('.wizrtable').closest('table').children('tr:second');
        var secondprice = $(secondrow()('#checkout .orderitems table.wizrtable tbody tr td.priceeach')).text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
        var thirdrow = $('.wizrtable').closest('table').children('tr:third');
        var thirdprice = $(thirdrow()('#checkout .orderitems table.wizrtable tbody tr td.priceeach')).text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
        // END: Define unit price

        // Define item IDs for each product
        var firstSKU = $(firstrow()('#checkout .orderitems table.wizrtable tbody .name .sku')).text().replace("Product Code: ", "");
        var secondSKU = $(secondrow()('#checkout .orderitems table.wizrtable tbody .name .sku')).text().replace("Product Code: ", "");
        var thirdSKU = $(thirdrow()('#checkout .orderitems table.wizrtable tbody .name .sku')).text().replace("Product Code: ", "");
        // END: Define item IDs for each product

        // Inject html div with result
        var Firstprodprice = jQuery("FirstprodPrice").text(firstprice);
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle Link:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/7HXBQ/10/

Any pointers?

Comment: There is only one table. Doing `$('.wizrtable').closest('table')` would probably resolve unpredictably, if not always referring to the .wizrtable itself. Just use `$('.wizrtable')`. Don't do this: `$(firstrow()('#checkout .orderitems table.wizrtable tbody tr td.priceeach'))`, do this `$(firstrow).find('.priceeach')`.

Comment: Something like this @JamesMcDonnell? (Not outputting result in Div):

http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/7HXBQ/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle was more or less correct. I've updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ht5nm/2/.

Some corrections:

```
var secondrow = $('.wizrtable').children('tr:second');
```

The second pseudo selector does not exist. use :nth-child(n). Also .children() only works on immediate children, so you still new the tbody in there... My bad.

```
var secondrow = $('.wizrtable tbody').children('tr:nth-child(2)');
```

Here I have no idea what the + in front of the variables was for. 
`if(+amountofproducts >= 4 && +amountofproducts <= 8)` however the variable depends on how many table rows you have, therefore the code inside the if statement would not run in your jsfiddle.

Also the code in your jsfiddle needed a #checkout to get some expected code to run, which I added into my jsfiddle.

The way you are going about this is not really going to be scalable to many table rows. For example you want to dynamically deal with rows instead of using firstrow secondrow thirdrow etc.

```
var Firstprodprice = jQuery("FirstprodPrice").text(firstprice);
```

This does not need to be assigned to a variable, as well the element with the class 'Firstprodprice' does not have a capital P in price. Therefore this line would not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

There appear some useful divs in your HTML that avoid the need for regexs.
This isn't tested, but something like ...

```
$('#wizrtable tr').each( function( index,element)  {
   var sku = $(element).find( 'div[title="pid"]').text();
   var qty = $(element).find( 'div[title="qty"]').text();
   var price = $(element).find( 'div[title="tv"]').text();
});
```

Comment: Something like this @vogomatix? Could you advise? (Still nothing in the result pane):
http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/7HXBQ/16/

Comment: I apologise for the brevity of the above answer - it was intended to get you started and I just did it in a 5 minute work break

Comment: Not to worry, @vogomatix. All is well now! --> http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/7HXBQ/20/

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the output, this removes the need to work out how many products there are in the table and scrapes the data for the entire table....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Define unit price
var tbody = $('.wizrtable tbody');
var prices = $(tbody).find('.priceeach');
var skus = $(tbody).find('.sku');
var quants = $(tbody).find('.quantity');
var product = [];

$(prices).each(function (idx) {
    product[idx] = {
        price: $(this).text().replace(/\u00A3/g, '')
    }
});
// END: Define unit price

// Define item IDs for each product
$(skus).each(function (idx) {
    product[idx].sku = $(this).text().replace("Product Code:", "");
});

$(quants).each(function (idx) {
    product[idx].qty = $(this).text();
});
// END: Define item IDs for each product

// Inject html div with result
// 1
$(".Firstprodprice").text(product[0].price);
$(".FirstSKU").text(product[0].sku);
$(".FirstQTY").text(product[0].qty);
// 2
$(".Secondprodprice").text(product[1].price);
$(".SecondSKU").text(product[1].sku);
$(".SecondQTY").text(product[1].qty);
// 3
$(".Thirdprodprice").text(product[2].price);
$(".ThirdSKU").text(product[2].sku);
$(".ThirdQTY").text(product[2].price);
});
```